# passing parameters to javascript function through OnClick html attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this error which is bugging me for a while now and I cant figure out how to fix it. It's probably something really stupid that I have overlooked and cant spot it.

but say I have this link on my page.

```
<a class=\"subbotbtn\" onclick=\" javascript:postdislike($pid, $username); \" href=\"#\"><img class='likeimg dislikeimg' src='images/dislike.png' /><span style=\"color:blue;\" class='reacttext'>Dislike</span></a>";
```

When I click it, its supposed to go to the javascript file and use this function here:

```
function postdislike(pid, user) {
"use strict";
alert("yay");
}
```

When I click, the alert never happens. Instead I end up getting this error:

```
VM85525 Ram:126 Uncaught ReferenceError: Ram is not defined onclick @ VM85525 Ram:126
```

"Ram" is the username I am passing through.
pid (post id) is another variable im passing through as a number (in this case, 60).

Can anyone please tell me what im doing wrong?

EDIT: also it might be helpful to add that this link is inside php echo statements, hence the extra slashes.

Comment: Take note, the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol is deprecated, and was originally intended for use in the `href` attribute, never in an event handler. At this point, it should just never be used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

fixed

```
<a class=\"subbotbtn\" onClick=\" postdislike('$pid', '$username'); \" href=\"#\"><img class='likeimg dislikeimg' src='images/dislike.png' /><span style=\"color:blue;\" class='reacttext'>Dislike</span></a>";
```

had to add single quotes around the parameters...